# ReactDOM.render inside index.js does not render my app and instead throws this error:

Tags: javascript, reactjs

> *Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object.  Check the render method of `Context.Consumer`.*

But the thing is I'm not using Context in my app, and the console of Visual Studio does not read any errors.

***index.js***

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css';
import App from './Components/App.js';

const container = document.getElementById('root')

ReactDOM.render(<App />, container)
```

***App.js***

```
import React from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter, Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom'
import Inicio from '../Pages/Inicio.js'
import Adopcion from '../Pages/Adopcion.js'
import NotFound from '../Components/NotFound.js'

const App = () => (
  <BrowserRouter>
        <Switch>
            <Route exact path='/inicio' component={<Inicio />}/>
            <Route exact path='/inicio/adoptar' component={<Adopcion />}/>
            <Route component={NotFound} />
        </Switch>
 </BrowserRouter>
)

export default App;
```

I spent all afternoon reading about Context, going back to the React documentation, but I don't know how to tell React to render my app. Thank you for answering.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your mistake is in your route declarations, specifically:

```
 component={<Inicio />}
```

and

```
 component={<Adopcion />}
```

What you're doing there is that you create instances, i.e. objects, of `Inicio` and `Adopcion` and passing those objects as the `component` prop to the route. As the error message says, it expects a function/class so you need to pass in the actual components, the same way you do with the `NotFound` route:

```
        <Route exact path='/inicio' component={Inicio}/>
        <Route exact path='/inicio/adoptar' component={Adopcion}/>
        <Route component={NotFound} />
```

The reason the error message mentions `Context.Consumer` is because that's what react-router uses internally to render your components and react-router doesn't validate what you passed in, it just passes it through.